# Undelegate stake with Daedalus wallet

Tags: cardano-cli, staking, daedalus

How do I undelegate (unstake) with Daedalus wallet to receive my 2 ADA deposit back. I remember used to be an option but it seem I can no longer find it. Is there is any way without actually using Yoroi wallet. I trying to minimize typing my keys into other wallets I rather lose those 2ada if there are no longer undelegation support for Daedalus.

Comment: can someone add tag unstake undelegate so others can find it. I have no enough reputation to create new tag

Comment: Donni, added the tag.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the feature has been removed from Daedalus. I suppose you can just transfer your ADA to another wallet. I'm curious what is the particular reason you want to undelegate? it seems like there's no downside.

Comment: There are various reasons why somebody would like to undelegate. Simply managing your portfolio for example:  Merging few wallets into one, selling off some of your wallets, creating new keys and moving your balance to new wallet for security concerns. There should be option to unstake or otherwise I wouldn't call 2 ada as deposit. For now as far as I know I need to take additional steps and install new wallet to take deposit which I wont do for security reasons. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an [issue open on Daedalus github](https://github.com/input-output-hk/daedalus/issues/2367) requesting this feature. Looking into the linked pull request, the feature appears to be complete but not enabled for the main client yet. Per Daedalus devs, the solution right now is to import the keys to Yoroi. You could do this after transferring out balance & rewards to minimize the security risks.

Comment: I wasn't aware that somebody pointed this out in github. I tried look for information and it seems nobody raised it on any forums. So i though I will ask here. Anybody could comeback and look it up. Perhaps its solved and in upcoming Daedalus update feature will be back. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way I got around this problem was to install Yoroi onto my mobile phone, ADDed a Shelley wallet and RESTORed each of my Daedalus wallets onto Yoroi.  By doing it this way I was able to get full access to all three of my Daedalus wallets.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you cannot undelegate in Daedalus 4.4 wallet but you can definitely do it using ***cardano-cli*** utility for getting the 2 ADA deposit back. Here's a deregistration command:

```
cardano-cli stake-address deregistration-certificate \
    --stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey \
    --out-file stake.cert
```

Then build a transaction:

```
stakeAddressDeposit=2000000

txOut=$((${totalBalance}+${stakeAddressDeposit}-${fee}))

cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
    --tx-in b64ae99e1195b04663ab863b62337e626c65b0c9444a9fbb9ef4458f81a6fe4#1 \
    --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+${txOut} \
    --invalid-hereafter $((${currentSlot}+10000)) \
    --fee ${fee} \
    --alonzo-era \
    --out-file tx.draft \
    --certificate-file stake.cert \
```