# Question about Daedalus deposit withdrawal

Tags: daedalus, staking

I'm willing to reorganize my wallets but as I read over here; https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/555/1927 this feature was "removed" (?!) from the Daedalus wallet and I know that there's an open "feature-request" topic over here; https://github.com/input-output-hk/daedalus/pull/2351

But I was wondering if anyone had any knowledge on the subject, like when it's planned to be added or why was it removed in the first place etc?

Comment: Please re-formulate this question so that the viewer doesn't have to navigate to several other links to understand what question you're asking. It will make it more useful to people searching later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about Daedalus deposit withdrawal and delegation privacy?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/questions-about-daedalus-deposit-withdrawal-and-delegation-privacy)

Comment: @intrinsic-values please don't mark things as a duplicate of a *closed* question!

Comment: I will vote to close it as it is better addressed by request for clarification and/or detail in the question that is referenced in the body of the question.  @user3152883, I think you will have more success with your efforts here if you follow the guidance at [ask]