# Is it possible to withdraw rewards with smart-contracts?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, rewards

I would like to automatically withdraw my rewards and send it in different wallets. Is it already technically possible?

Thanks,
Regards,
Anthony

**Edit - A Use Case for this:**
A possible use case for this would be if you were a SPO (Stake Pool Operator) with multiple pool owners (or multiple pledging wallets). A stake pool can only have *1 reward address*, therefore every time there are rewards, a manual distribution must take place to distribute to all owners/pledgers. With a smart contract, you could potentially automate this distribution to the owners/pledgers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a smart contract. Rewards from staking/delegating are never "locked" on Cardano, you can send immediately at any time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a smart contract when you withdraw rewards. Staking and everything related to it does not block funds in your wallet. You are free to transfer your money, including ***staking rewards***, to another wallet at any time. As far as you know, to begin staking, every new validator must freeze 2 ADA, that’s a ***register key deposit***. You’ll get 2 ADA back when you ***[undelegate](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/547/undelegate-stake-with-daedalus-wallet/4200#4200)***.